# Updating table using PDO : Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im making a function to change the password from the table user, but im getting a syntax error

Here is the function:

```
 public function changepassword($password, $newpassword) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION["userSession"];
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=:user_id");
        $stmt->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($password = $userRow['password']) {
            $sql = "UPDATE user set password=:password WHERE user_id=:user_id";
            $stmt2 = $this->db->query($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id, ":password" => $password ));
            $stmt2->execute();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the function call

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-save'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
    $newpassword2 = $_POST['newpassword2'];

    if ($newpassword == $newpassword2) {
        if ($user->changepassword($password, $newpassword)) {
            header("Location: selfedit.php?inserted");
        } else {
            header("Location: selfedit.php?failure");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: selfedit.php?failurematch");
    }
}
```

This is the error i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':password
>   WHERE user_id=:user_id' at line 1' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php:37 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php(37): PDO->query('UPDATE user
>   set...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\selfedit.php(8):
>   USER->changepassword('fereira', 'umdois') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php on line 37

**EDIT 1**

I changed the functions according to this question comments, getting a different error

```
public function changepassword($password, $newpassword) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION["userSession"];
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id));
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($password == $userRow['password']) {
        $sql = "UPDATE user set password=:newpassword WHERE user_id=:user_id";
        $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt2->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id, ":password" => $newpassword ));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

New error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php:37 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php(37):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\selfedit.php(8):
>   USER->changepassword('ferreira', 'anotherpass') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php on line 37

Comment: I don't use PDO, but that's probably `prepare()`, not `query()`.

Comment: @Blackhole is correct. `query()` is for simple queries, but `prepare()/execute()` must be used with parameters.

Comment: You've got 2 `execute()` in the if - $stmt with bindings, and $stmt2 that doesn't. That'll be the cause of your error.

Comment: Incorrect comparison. `$password = $userRow['password']` That sets `$password`.

Comment: @TylerSebastian you should include the colon in the binding. The driver currently auto appends it but if they remove that feature in the future you might be out of luck.

Comment: @chris85 ah ok, thanks - we're using a couple different PDOs/wrappers and they all don't use the colon.

Comment: `:password` wrong parameter name. Should be `:newpassword`... or change name in query. Either or need to match up though.

Comment: Its working now, i added an answer with the line changed and the final function

Answer (score 1):

It works by changing, from **EDIT 1**, this line:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE user set password=:newpassword WHERE user_id=:user_id";
```

To this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user set password=:newpassword WHERE user_id=:user_id";
```

Final Function:

```
public function changepassword($password, $newpassword) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION["userSession"];
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id));
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($password == $userRow['password']) {
        $sql = "UPDATE user set password=:password WHERE user_id=:user_id";
        $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt2->execute(array(":user_id" => $user_id, ":password" => $newpassword ));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```